# Reduktion von Adjektiven (Gegenteil zur Steigerung)

Tags: adjective, diminutive

Können die Adjektive im Deutschen neben einer Steigerungsform auch eine Reduktionsform bilden?
Zum Beispiel anhand des Hilfswortes *weniger:*

Ich habe bemerkt, dass es Adjektive gibt, die keine *un*-Formen oder keine Antonyme haben, und infolgedessen kann ich so etwas nicht sagen:

> Machen Sie bitte das Essen unpikanter.

Stattdessen sage ich in Analogie zum Englischen:

> Machen Sie bitte das Essen weniger pikant.
>   Please make the meal less spicy.

Ist das überhaupt korrekt?

Auch wenn es ein Antonym gibt, möchte ich manchmal eine Reduktionsform anstatt einer Steigerungsform des Antonyms verwenden, weil es für mich anders klingt und andere Bedeutung hat, oder mir ein richtiges Antonym nicht einfällt.

> Das ist für mich weniger verständlich als jenes.

Das bedeutet, dass das für mich ja schon verständlich ist, aber doch etwas weniger.

> Das ist für mich unverständlicher als jenes.

Das bedeutet, dass das und jenes für mich nicht verständlich sind, aber es ist das, was ich z.B. äußern will.

Wie unten gesagt, ist die *weniger*–Konstruktion richtig.
Gibt es aber eine Superlative-Version, z.B:

> Das ist für mich am wenigsten verständlich.

Comment: Das englische "spicy" würde ich übrigens als scharf und nicht als pikant übersetzen.

Comment: @Iris hat recht, wenn es um Essen geht und nicht um beispielsweise einen Bericht über jemandes sexuelle Eskapaden.

Comment: Ok, die Wörter sind aber ähnlich, pikant ist für mich = etwas scharf. Darüber hinaus musste ich "pikant" auf Englisch übersetzen und nicht umgekehrt.

Comment: Die Konstruktion mit ›weniger‹ ist richtig. Eine Reduktionsform gibt es nicht im Deutschen und auch in keiner anderen Sprache, die ich kenne. Wobei man immer im Blick haben muss, dass auch die Steigerung nur ein Konstrukt unseres Verstands ist und im hartcodierten Bereich des Sprachzentrums nicht existiert.

Comment: @deponensvogel, wenn, wie du sagst, "›weniger‹ ist richtig", dann existiert schon (doch) eine Reduktionsform. Der letzten Aussage wegen der Steigerung stimme ich nicht zu, da es eine Regel gibt, mit der man die Formen bildet (-er, -st..)

Comment: Statt "weniger pikant" koennte man auf "milder" ausweichen. Und "weniger verständlich" und "unverständlicher " sind wirklich nicht sehr verschieden. Wenn X unverständlicher  ist als Y, muss Y doch zumindest ein bisschen verständlich sein. Verschiedene Grade von (Un)verständlichkeit sind nunmal nicht klar definierbar.

Comment: @oW_ Ich widerspreche! "weniger verständlich" und "unverständlicher" sind sehr verschieden! Eine Erklärung kann beispielsweise "weniger verständlich" sein als eine andere. *Beide sind jedoch generell verständlich*. Wenn eine Erklärung "unverständlicher" ist als eine andere, dann sind *beide unverständlich*, nur ist es im die erste noch schlimmer bestellt. Das sind völlig unterschiedliche Qualitäten!

Comment: @Denis: Die Steigerung von Adjektiven ist eine Sekundärerscheinung einer räumlichen Determination durch die Suffixe -er und -st, die sich mit verwandten Formen durch den gesamten indogermanischen Sprachbaum zieht. | Wenn der Vorgang, ein einfaches Adverb dranzuhängen, eine Reduktionsform ist, dann bitte. Dann muss für dich ›Das ist höchst unverständlich‹ auch eine Superlativform sein.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Was sagst du zu "Hans ist größer als Franz" vs. "Franz ist kleiner als Hans"?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Das sind ganz normale Relationen. Hierdurch wird aus meiner Sicht keine Aussage getroffen, ob Franz nun groß (Beispiel 1) oder Hans nun klein (Beispiel 2) ist. Die Beispiele hinken aber aus meiner Sicht im Vergleich mit "weniger verständlich" vs. "unverständlicher". Um das vergleichen zu können, müssten deine Beispiele beispielsweise lauten "Hans ist weniger riesig als Franz" und "Hans ist winziger als Franz". Und schon hast Du eine Aussage über Franz' Größe.

Comment: ThorstenDittmar Ich war mir auch nicht ganz sicher, wo das von Dir empfundene/beschriebene Pähnomen herkommt. Aber es ist jedenfalls eine Erkenntnis, dass nicht per se in der Richtung des Vergleichs eine Aussage zu liegen scheint. Augenscheinlich muss das für den vergleich herangezogene Adjektiv besonders "qualizierend" wirken, oder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntaktisch gibt es die Reduktion nicht. Semantisch gibt es die Möglichkeiten mit `"weniger" + Antonym` oder mit `"un" + Komparativ`. Beide sind in der Regel korrekt, aber folgendes ist zu beachten:

Die Reduktion nach dem Schema `"weniger" + Antonym` (also beispielsweise: *weniger schön*) ist in vielen Fällen stilistisch gesehen eine [Litotes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) und kann etwa ein Ironiesignal sein. Die Bedeutung ist also mit anderen Nuancen versehen.

Die Reduktion nach dem Schema `"un" + Komparativ` ist nicht immer korrekt; und zwar dann, wenn der verneinte Positiv des Adjektivs gar nicht steigerbar ist. Dein Beispiel *unverständlicher* fällt in meinen Augen in diese Kategorie. Ich meine, dass *unverständlich* nicht steigerbar ist.

Im konkreten Einzelfall kann man sicherlich streiten, aber jedenfalls sollte man beachten, ob die Steigerung des verneinten Adjektivs unsemantisch ist.

Answer (score 4):

In keiner mir bekannten Sprache (auch nicht Finnisch, also eine nicht-indogermanische Sprache – dort regelmäßige Steigerung von *schlecht:* *huono – huonompi)* existieren negative Steigerungen oder Reduktionen. Zwar wird in einigen Sprachen das Antonym von *gut* – *schlecht* – unregelmäßig gebeugt (Englisch: *worse*, Französisch: *pire),* was Schülern dieser Sprachen regelmäßig Ärger macht, aber letztendlich handelt es sich dabei nicht um eine Reduktion sondern um einen Zweischrittvorgang: Erst invertieren, dann die Inversion steigern.

Auch das Deutsche fällt in diese Kategorie. Eine *Antisteigerung* existiert grammatikalisch nicht. Stattdessen wird entweder das Gegenteil gesteigert oder eine Umschreibung mit *weniger* gewählt. *Weniger* ist eine regelmäßigere Steigerung von *wenig.*

Comment: also du ebenso wie deponensvogel habt meine Frage beantwortet, ob die "weniger" Konstruktion korrekt ist. Also: Steigerung = -er, -st, Reduktion = "weniger".

Answer (score 0):

Beide Varianten sind grundsätzlich richtig. Entweder verwendet man *weniger* oder die Steigerungsform des Gegenteils.

Wie du richtig bemerkst, kann man nicht bei jedem Adjektiv mit dem Präfix *un-* das Gegenteil bilden. *Unpikanter* würde man zwar verstehen, allerdings ist dieses Wort vollkommen ungebräuchlich. Hier solltest du also *weniger pikant* (besser *weniger scharf*) verwenden. Genauso funktioniert auch *nicht so* als Alternative zu *weniger*: *Bitte machen Sie das Essen nicht so scharf*.

*Unverständlich* ist hingegen ein gebräuchliches Wort. Hier sind sowohl *weniger verständlich*, *nicht so verständlich*, als auch *unverständlicher* möglich. (Die Meinung in dem Kommentar von Thorsten Dittmar teile ich nicht.)

Aus stilistischen Gründen solltest du allerdings *weniger* vermeiden, wenn es ein eigenes Adjektiv für das Gegenteil gibt. Beispielsweise solltest du anstatt *weniger klein* immer die Bezeichnung *größer* verwenden, oder *günstiger* anstatt *weniger teuer*. Die Konstruktion mit *nicht so* ist flexibler. Formulierungen wie *nicht so teuer* oder *nicht so groß* sind durchaus gebräuchlich.

Nach denselben Richtlinien kannst du *am wenigsten* oder das Superlativ des Gegenteils verwenden.

Comment: Die Meinung von Thorsten Dittmar teile ich, deswegen –1.

Comment: Ich bin es auch, aber für die Mühe +1.

Comment: @Denis: Für die Mühe sollst Du keine Upvotes vergeben, sondern ausschließlich entlang des Kriteriums "useful/not useful". Nicht für Fleiß, Sympathie, gute Absicht, zur Begrüßung, Originalität, Witz, politische Übereinstimmung, auf Gegenseitigkeit, usw. Und was bist Du auch - eine Meinung?