# Welche Grammatik ist "weniger falsch"?

Tags: spelling

Satz aus einem Konfigurationshandbuch: (es geht um einen Dateipfad)

> Diesen finden Sie im in der Main.xml konfigurierten Verzeichnis

gegenüber

> Diesen finden Sie im in der Main.xml konfiguriertem Verzeichnis

*Im konfiguriertem Verzeichnis* klingt richtig, aber andererseits klingt *im konfigurierten Verzeichnis* auch nicht falsch ...

Beim Plural wäre natürlich nur *konfigurierten* richtig.

Was ist "weniger falsch" ?

Comment: "die Main.xml" empfinde ich als sehr fragwürdig gegenüber "die Datei Main.xml" oder "die Main.xml-Datei".

Comment: *im konfiguriertem Verzeichnis* klingt deshalb falsch, weil es falsch ist.

Comment: Ich würde es umsegeln: "Diesen finden Sie im Verzeichnis, das in main.xml konfiguriert ist." Der erste Satz ist zwar richtig, klingt aber komisch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der erste Satz ist korrekt, der zweite nicht.

Die Kurzform wäre:

> Diesen finden Sie im konfigurierten Verzeichnis.

Analog zu

> Ich fand ihn im linken Kellerraum.
>   Ich trug ihn im starken Arm.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt weder »mehr falsch« noch »weniger falsch« weil es auch weder »mehr richtig« noch »weniger richtig« gibt. Allenfalls könnte man die Fehler zählen, und von Sätzen mit mehr oder weniger Fehlern sprechen.

Unter der Prämisse, dass *»Main.xml«* tatsächlich weiblich ist, ist von deinen beiden Sätzen ist der erste richtig und der zweite falsch.

Aber der richtige Satz ist stilistisch schlecht.

Zu allererst würde ich *»Main.xml«* durch *»Datei Main.xml«* oder *»File Main.xml«* ersetzen, dann steht nämlich das Geschlecht außer Zweifel:

> Diesen finden Sie im *in der Datei Main.xml* konfigurierten Verzeichnis.
>   Diesen finden Sie im *im File Main.xml* konfigurierten Verzeichnis.

Und als nächsten Schritt würde ich die Konfiguration nicht in einem vorangestellten Attribut erwähnen, sondern in einem nachgestellten Attributsatz:

> Diesen finden Sie im Verzeichnis, das in der Datei Main.xml konfiguriert ist.
>   Diesen finden Sie im Verzeichnis, das im File Main.xml konfiguriert ist.

Comment: »weniger richtig« geht doch oder ?
https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31840/reduktion-von-adjektiven-gegenteil-zur-steigerung

Comment: @Denis Naja, richtig ist aber nicht einfach irgendein Adjektiv.

Comment: Ich würde "der Datei" weglassen: "Diesen finden Sie im Verzeichnis, das in main.xml konfiguriert ist." Reicht m.E völlig aus.

Answer (score -2):

> Diesen finden Sie im in der Main.xml konfigurierten Verzeichnis

Der Satz klingt - auch als richtigere Lösung - sprachlich und insbesondere aus Sicht der technischen Erläuterung für den Nutzer der Software etwas verdreht. Allerdings wird aus der Frage nicht ganz deutlich, was hier technisch eigentlich gemeint ist.

Vorschläge:

> Diesen finden Sie in der Datei Main.xml im konfigurierten Verzeichnis.
>
> Diesen Dateipfad finden Sie im Abschnitt <...> der Konfigurationsdatei `Main.xml`.

Comment: Ich weiß natürlich nicht, was ursprünglich gemeint war, aber der Satz ist, so wie er in der Frage steht, eigentlich ziemlich eindeutig: Irgendetwas kann in einem Verzeichnis gefunden werden. Das besagte Verzeichnis ist jenes, welches in der Datei Main.xml konfiguriert wurde.